# Linux shell script error caused by using the output of the file command in Linux to analyze images?

Tags: image, shell

```
echo "enter filename"

read filename

fileData=$(file $filename)

if [ $fileData == *"PNG image"* ]
then
echo "this is a PNG file"

elif [ $fileData == *"JPEG image"* ]
then
echo "this is a JPEG file"

elif [ $fileData == *"GIF image"* ]
then
echo "this is a GIF file"

else
echo "error"

fi
```

So I can't figure out what is wrong with this exactly but it returns the following output with bef0e2e9181980f0d6d23e6c057a47d2 being the file name:

```
0.sh: 7: [: bef0e2e9181980f0d6d23e6c057a47d2:: unexpected operator
0.sh: 11: [: bef0e2e9181980f0d6d23e6c057a47d2:: unexpected operator
0.sh: 15: [: bef0e2e9181980f0d6d23e6c057a47d2:: unexpected operator
error
```

but when I run "file bef0e2e9181980f0d6d23e6c057a47d2" I get

```
bef0e2e9181980f0d6d23e6c057a47d2: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPCM), density 37x37, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1365x767, frames 3
```

So to make a long story short, my ultimate goal here is to make a script to help me identify image file types because I have many images without extensions. I will eventually replace the echo commands under the if and elifs with actions to rename the files with the correct extensions. But anyways, it looks to me as though the output of the command which I am attempting to store in variable is for some reason not being stored as a string causing these issues, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put double quotes around your fileData variables:

if [ "$fileData" == *"PNG image"* ]

Comment: Gave that a try. Now it outputs this 3 times:

'0.sh: 15: [: fffd321300f53319a4f236b3224494ef: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 72x72, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=7, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=98, yresolution=106, resolutionunit=3, software=Paint.NET v3.10, datetime=2005:06:27 11:27:30], baseline, precision 8, 640x632, frames 3: unexpected operator'

so it is still not properly executing the if and seeing it as an "unexpected operator", why?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "enter filename"

read filename

fileData=$(file "$filename")

if [[ "$fileData" == *"PNG image"* ]]
then
echo "this is a PNG file"

elif [[ "$fileData" == *"JPEG image"* ]]
then
echo "this is a JPEG file"

elif [[ "$fileData" == *"GIF image"* ]]
then
echo "this is a GIF file"

else
echo "error"

fi
```

I ran this version with bash instead of sh. It works. And here's the fully functional script that does everything I want if anyone wants it (dumps the properly marked files into a folder named 0):

```
for filename in *
do

fileData=$(file "$filename")

if [[ "$fileData" == *"PNG image"* ]]
then
mv "$filename" "0/$filename .png"

elif [[ "$fileData" == *"JPEG image"* ]]
then
mv "$filename" "0/$filename .jpg"

elif [[ "$fileData" == *"GIF image"* ]]
then
mv "$filename" "0/$filename .gif"

else
echo "error"

fi

done
```